# "Contains" is not working, controller asp.net

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

Currently I'm making web app using asp.net core and angular. I tried to use "Contains" in a controller, it's working when I use a string, for example: `.Contains("Galletas")` but when I use parameter it's not working, for example : `.Contains(nombre)`.

I use a service with angular to call method controller the database information.

I have validated the parameter "nombre", it have information and is not null.

"Galletas" is anything var, I used "Galletas" how an example to test query. You can see var "nombre", i want that query is working with parameter "nombre". Really thank you to help me.

[image: Break point]
[image: return length: 0]

**Controller code**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{nombre}")]
public IEnumerable<ProductoCLS> filtrarProductosPorNombre(string nombre)
{
    using (BDRestauranteContext bd = new BDRestauranteContext())
    {
        List<ProductoCLS> lista = (from producto in bd.Producto
                                   join categoria in bd.Categoria
                                   on producto.Iidcategoria equals
                                   categoria.Iidcategoria
                                   where producto.Bhabilitado == 1
                                   && producto.Nombre.ToLower().Contains(nombre.ToLower())
                                   select new ProductoCLS
                                   {
                                       idproducto = producto.Iidproducto,
                                       nombre = producto.Nombre,
                                       precio = (decimal)producto.Precio,
                                       stock = (int)producto.Stock,
                                       nombreCategoria = categoria.Nombre

                                   }).ToList();
        return lista;

    } 
}
```

**When I use string ("Galletas") into Contains is working**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{nombre}")]
public IEnumerable<ProductoCLS> filtrarProductosPorNombre(string nombre)
{
    using (BDRestauranteContext bd = new BDRestauranteContext())
    {
        List<ProductoCLS> lista = (from producto in bd.Producto
                                   join categoria in bd.Categoria
                                   on producto.Iidcategoria equals
                                   categoria.Iidcategoria
                                   where producto.Bhabilitado == 1
                                   //&& producto.Nombre.ToLower().Contains(nombre.ToLower())
                                   && producto.Nombre.Contains("Galletas")
                                   select new ProductoCLS
                                   {
                                       idproducto = producto.Iidproducto,
                                       nombre = producto.Nombre,
                                       precio = (decimal)producto.Precio,
                                       stock = (int)producto.Stock,
                                       nombreCategoria = categoria.Nombre

                                   }).ToList();
        return lista;

    }
}
```

**Angular service code**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductoService {

  urlBase: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

    // urlBase tiene el nombre del dominio
    this.urlBase = baseUrl;

  }

  public getProducto() {
    return this.http.get(this.urlBase + 'api/Producto/listarProductos');
    //  .subscribe(data => {
    //    console.log(data);
    //  });
  }


  public filtrarProductosPorNombre(nombre) {
    return this.http.get(this.urlBase + 'api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{' + nombre + '}');

  }
}
```

Comment: You should check the case sensitiviness, try removing the toLower

Comment: what is the collation of your database, check for Case sensitivity

Comment: Hold up. "Galletas" is working, what about "galletas" (since that would be an equivalent test to how you're handling `nombre`)?

Comment: Show the URL being called that populates the variable. Based on the image it looks like you are actually calling a URL ending with `/{Galletas}`  and not `/Galletas`

Comment: "Galletas" is anything var, I used "Galletas" how an example to test query. You can see var "nombre", i want that query is working with var "nombre". Really thank you to help me.

Comment: @FelipeMoreno You still have not shown how you call the URL that is failing when called.

Comment: Show the URL and the "Error", maybe it is really working but it has no data.

Comment: I tried this query: Nombre.Contains(nombre). It haven't toLower but stil don't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image it looks like you are actually calling a URL ending with `/{Galletas}` and not `/Galletas`

This line in the angular service code

```
return this.http.get(this.urlBase + 'api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{' + nombre + '}');
```

is adding additional curly brackets `{..}` around the passed parameter ine the generated URL

Depending on the passed `Value`, the URL will end up looking like

```
api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{Value}
```

which will not match your records since the model binder will take the literal string as `"{Value}"`.

Remove the curly brackets from your code constructing the URL

```
return this.http.get(this.urlBase + 'api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/' + nombre);
```

In the controller, the curly brackets in the Route template

```
[Route("api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{nombre}")]
```

represent a route template parameter placeholder. It is not literally needed in the URL when making the request.

Answer (score 2):

I see in the first image, under the locals list the value of nombre is equal to "{Galletas}", it should be "Galletas"

The {} in this just means it is a parameter.

```
[Route("api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/{nombre}")]
```

So the call from Angular should be:

```
api/Producto/filtrarProductosPorNombre/Galletas
```

Comment: "Galletas" is anything var, I used "Galletas" how an example to test query. You can see var "nombre", i want that query is working with var "nombre". Really thank you to help me.